# Subset, or reclassify, spatial data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial, spatstat

I have the following data that indicates how many points occur within each rectangle (spatial data generated with `quadratcount()` from the `spatstat` package):

```
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 2L, 62L, 164L, 0L, 34L, 16L, 219L, 
16L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 257L, 553L, 58L, 161L, 
169L, 78L, 39L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 49L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 216L, 
791L, 627L, 208L, 205L, 0L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 
0L, 169L, 179L, 5L, 124L, 424L, 691L, 562L, 73L, 130L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 249L, 450L, 97L, 154L, 218L, 123L, 
151L, 304L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 242L, 
86L, 348L, 226L, 75L, 8L, 561L, 307L, 312L, 0L, 61L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 106L, 334L, 359L, 587L, 
375L, 381L, 66L, 40L, 106L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 124L, 47L, 60L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 105L, 117L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 123L, 587L, 341L, 338L, 222L, 231L, 46L, 0L, 27L, 64L, 
0L, 15L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 140L, 282L, 395L, 112L, 
184L, 194L, 244L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 136L, 217L, 11L, 20L, 40L, 114L, 
597L, 227L, 146L, 55L, 7L, 12L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 16L, 252L, 201L, 
9L, 5L, 0L, 55L, 0L, 17L, 9L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 98L, 480L, 270L, 0L, 109L, 298L, 
385L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 196L, 247L, 86L, 184L, 422L, 628L, 357L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 255L, 206L, 88L, 0L, 41L, 224L, 
4L, 0L, 106L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 21L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 85L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 
319L, 141L, 351L, 421L, 810L, 331L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 216L, 67L, 18L, 
0L, 96L, 313L, 2L, 41L, 17L, 17L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 68L, 353L, 122L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 65L, 
141L, 72L, 32L, 49L, 34L, 0L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 82L, 309L, 343L, 0L, 
253L, 473L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 187L, 163L, 2L, 270L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 10L, 151L, 117L, 
25L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 14L, 416L, 29L, 164L, 93L, 
120L, 202L, 203L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 210L, 538L, 178L, 183L, 416L, 51L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 98L, 152L, 115L, 289L, 18L, 81L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 35L, 7L, 0L, 2L, 29L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 107L, 312L, 322L, 192L, 361L, 694L, 
555L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 319L, 131L, 920L, 394L, 48L, 230L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 154L, 146L, 9L, 8L, 32L, 20L, 4L, 48L, 0L, 0L, 
16L, 0L, 345L, 68L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 
0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 208L, 131L, 332L, 419L, 117L, 448L, 144L, 
0L, 75L, 83L, 53L, 360L, 8L, 29L, 685L, 749L, 134L, 8L, 0L, 33L, 
0L, 0L, 86L, 38L, 7L, 0L, 170L, 202L, 118L, 94L, 238L, 326L, 
115L, 244L, 62L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
26L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 183L, 396L, 45L, 0L, 80L, 0L, 0L, 172L, 
629L, 143L, 418L, 51L, 36L, 603L, 834L, 549L, 91L, 156L, 12L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 129L, 17L, 108L, 299L, 161L, 177L, 30L, 0L, 
64L, 57L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 59L, 5L, 62L, 111L, 36L, 2L, 
24L, 0L, 0L, 98L, 26L, 140L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 53L, 199L, 
406L, 413L, 107L, 678L, 1066L, 960L, 575L, 391L, 622L, 372L, 
76L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 208L, 171L, 16L, 17L, 22L, 0L, 15L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 17L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 67L, 0L, 0L, 66L, 
9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 110L, 33L, 0L, 2L, 247L, 647L, 
375L, 696L, 466L, 1367L, 1066L, 442L, 664L, 636L, 467L, 32L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 10L, 30L, 55L, 71L, 177L, 149L, 44L, 5L, 0L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 135L, 0L, 46L, 47L, 240L, 228L, 20L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 598L, 379L, 0L, 0L, 79L, 696L, 
510L, 83L, 203L, 351L, 1030L, 900L, 646L, 610L, 635L, 347L, 18L, 
1L, 0L, 59L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 26L, 31L, 11L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 234L, 8L, 147L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
7L, 66L, 0L, 0L, 376L, 953L, 366L, 236L, 217L, 228L, 518L, 509L, 
112L, 140L, 437L, 562L, 354L, 763L, 697L, 408L, 310L, 54L, 28L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 25L, 69L, 171L, 315L, 12L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 35L, 406L, 394L, 802L, 469L, 852L, 6L, 371L, 451L, 742L, 
245L, 728L, 1115L, 544L, 681L, 901L, 645L, 457L, 517L, 161L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 18L, 235L, 280L, 35L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 4L, 12L, 0L, 3L, 12L, 
12L, 70L, 215L, 53L, 402L, 544L, 0L, 55L, 105L, 543L, 875L, 687L, 
459L, 1110L, 1732L, 1411L, 725L, 771L, 587L, 829L, 69L, 0L, 0L, 
23L, 334L, 387L, 416L, 355L, 367L, 160L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 326L, 69L, 0L, 9L, 165L, 43L, 110L, 44L, 67L, 
0L, 37L, 0L, 0L, 310L, 0L, 83L, 408L, 183L, 8L, 169L, 560L, 625L, 
916L, 345L, 758L, 1118L, 1258L, 1133L, 819L, 922L, 226L, 0L, 
43L, 86L, 153L, 188L, 22L, 93L, 411L, 434L, 255L, 238L, 278L, 
282L, 161L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 49L, 21L, 97L, 
531L, 436L, 271L, 28L, 1L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 317L, 667L, 396L, 
9L, 3L, 719L, 1070L, 768L, 1496L, 938L, 1135L, 1432L, 367L, 703L, 
824L, 557L, 517L, 426L, 476L, 530L, 517L, 184L, 759L, 124L, 178L, 
477L, 499L, 155L, 197L, 257L, 35L, 8L, 77L, 21L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 248L, 480L, 26L, 19L, 128L, 9L, 220L, 364L, 183L, 
490L, 669L, 656L, 447L, 589L, 682L, 893L, 693L, 861L, 1117L, 
1142L, 1403L, 1256L, 1185L, 680L, 232L, 268L, 520L, 586L, 325L, 
520L, 278L, 648L, 10L, 317L, 409L, 290L, 234L, 50L, 166L, 50L, 
22L, 140L, 192L, 75L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 65L, 10L, 43L, 
0L, 6L, 138L, 645L, 632L, 372L, 739L, 720L, 552L, 256L, 637L, 
705L, 896L, 981L, 711L, 820L, 1486L, 1377L, 1028L, 106L, 556L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 124L, 344L, 456L, 197L, 125L, 214L, 348L, 58L, 
46L, 8L, 9L, 144L, 546L, 259L, 177L, 20L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 60L, 679L, 438L, 707L, 1002L, 846L, 832L, 
834L, 262L, 561L, 499L, 768L, 877L, 1185L, 1597L, 1041L, 876L, 
680L, 186L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 282L, 312L, 384L, 391L, 
61L, 244L, 213L, 129L, 9L, 0L, 111L, 333L, 181L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 153L, 475L, 633L, 197L, 
561L, 555L, 529L, 691L, 456L, 40L, 71L, 286L, 660L, 624L, 438L, 
673L, 524L, 1055L, 957L, 492L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 218L, 
383L, 317L, 239L, 298L, 110L, 163L, 55L, 64L, 176L, 184L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 158L, 194L, 0L, 73L, 607L, 786L, 575L, 
570L, 125L, 564L, 635L, 632L, 515L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 371L, 513L, 
589L, 804L, 808L, 916L, 645L, 944L, 260L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 56L, 231L, 260L, 255L, 287L, 330L, 267L, 72L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 430L, 717L, 0L, 169L, 713L, 597L, 
621L, 402L, 40L, 201L, 458L, 615L, 438L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 
274L, 352L, 334L, 622L, 720L, 596L, 167L, 406L, 318L, 54L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 102L, 706L, 517L, 636L, 85L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 60L, 18L, 109L, 338L, 577L, 178L, 
307L, 310L, 237L, 3L, 182L, 84L, 502L, 499L, 79L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
189L, 233L, 31L, 162L, 87L, 350L, 422L, 370L, 357L, 208L, 239L, 
207L, 158L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 212L, 266L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 66L, 247L, 163L, 211L, 798L, 199L, 619L, 
55L, 0L, 249L, 264L, 399L, 44L, 453L, 78L, 844L, 652L, 24L, 0L, 
0L, 112L, 129L, 55L, 69L, 43L, 64L, 93L, 193L, 322L, 510L, 399L, 
358L, 333L, 208L, 103L, 371L, 138L, 60L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 136L, 122L, 209L, 300L, 556L, 365L, 
212L, 107L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 93L, 270L, 450L, 223L, 723L, 651L, 428L, 
50L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 485L, 103L, 140L, 224L, 
121L, 163L, 93L, 197L, 186L, 272L, 575L, 337L, 107L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 312L, 572L, 389L, 
541L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 285L, 454L, 542L, 224L, 463L, 688L, 
120L, 58L, 0L, 114L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 2L, 111L, 629L, 210L, 0L, 172L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 112L, 160L, 180L, 275L, 498L, 240L, 72L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 92L, 186L, 216L, 41L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 186L, 572L, 333L, 401L, 492L, 124L, 175L, 318L, 
74L, 35L, 345L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 255L, 422L, 358L, 85L, 214L, 
216L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 87L, 49L, 72L, 114L, 117L, 184L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 237L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 135L, 198L, 358L, 373L, 231L, 146L, 421L, 428L, 4L, 0L, 
118L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 304L, 457L, 129L, 285L, 198L, 28L, 
0L, 229L, 227L, 114L, 0L, 83L, 16L, 232L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 183L, 91L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
111L, 4L, 76L, 238L, 132L, 460L, 435L, 777L, 194L, 0L, 10L, 121L, 
128L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 9L, 265L, 263L, 1L, 0L, 35L, 170L, 
30L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 59L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 11L, 208L, 16L, 0L, 1L, 188L, 449L, 311L, 243L, 
203L, 64L, 457L, 493L, 615L, 361L, 94L, 1L, 78L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 83L, 18L, 167L, 184L, 116L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
10L, 244L, 442L, 225L, 45L, 39L, 362L, 206L, 403L, 348L, 118L, 
21L, 356L, 515L, 547L, 194L, 181L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 89L, 224L, 
61L, 0L, 0L, 46L, 6L, 200L, 225L, 103L, 92L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 
343L, 408L, 0L, 14L, 68L, 547L, 472L, 139L, 40L, 312L, 280L, 
634L, 380L, 125L, 19L, 0L, 39L, 2L, 54L, 92L, 27L, 316L, 150L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 90L, 320L, 62L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 178L, 529L, 44L, 
0L, 71L, 276L, 170L, 186L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 14L, 185L, 185L, 34L, 
21L, 0L, 132L, 75L, 46L, 18L, 178L, 49L, 12L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 
178L, 89L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 201L, 42L, 51L, 227L, 37L, 72L, 
71L, 140L, 169L, 0L, 0L, 163L, 41L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 264L, 387L, 8L, 
246L, 289L, 149L, 293L, 107L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 32L, 39L, 18L, 21L, 
4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 152L, 124L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 356L, 121L, 46L, 
0L, 145L, 119L, 0L, 23L, 146L, 69L, 298L, 220L, 0L, 93L, 249L, 
227L, 55L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 134L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 28L, 163L, 19L, 3L, 56L, 2L, 153L, 332L, 
81L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 108L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 16L, 51L, 127L, 
92L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 126L, 36L, 536L, 727L, 70L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 30L, 3L, 51L, 190L, 228L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 62L, 180L, 476L, 442L, 65L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 0L, 64L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 158L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 116L, 
257L, 354L, 125L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 244L, 188L, 
9L, 0L, 1L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 90L, 93L, 301L, 151L, 160L, 228L, 151L, 18L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 114L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 90L, 
117L, 483L, 340L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 117L, 156L, 98L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(50L, 
50L), .Dimnames = list(y = c("[1.2588e+06,1.2593e+06]", "[1.2584e+06,1.2588e+06)", 
"[1.2579e+06,1.2584e+06)", "[1.2575e+06,1.2579e+06)", "[1.257e+06,1.2575e+06)", 
"[1.2566e+06,1.257e+06)", "[1.2561e+06,1.2566e+06)", "[1.2557e+06,1.2561e+06)", 
"[1.2552e+06,1.2557e+06)", "[1.2548e+06,1.2552e+06)", "[1.2543e+06,1.2548e+06)", 
"[1.2539e+06,1.2543e+06)", "[1.2534e+06,1.2539e+06)", "[1.253e+06,1.2534e+06)", 
"[1.2525e+06,1.253e+06)", "[1.2521e+06,1.2525e+06)", "[1.2516e+06,1.2521e+06)", 
"[1.2512e+06,1.2516e+06)", "[1.2507e+06,1.2512e+06)", "[1.2503e+06,1.2507e+06)", 
"[1.2498e+06,1.2503e+06)", "[1.2494e+06,1.2498e+06)", "[1.2489e+06,1.2494e+06)", 
"[1.2485e+06,1.2489e+06)", "[1.248e+06,1.2485e+06)", "[1.2476e+06,1.248e+06)", 
"[1.2471e+06,1.2476e+06)", "[1.2467e+06,1.2471e+06)", "[1.2462e+06,1.2467e+06)", 
"[1.2458e+06,1.2462e+06)", "[1.2453e+06,1.2458e+06)", "[1.2449e+06,1.2453e+06)", 
"[1.2444e+06,1.2449e+06)", "[1.244e+06,1.2444e+06)", "[1.2435e+06,1.244e+06)", 
"[1.2431e+06,1.2435e+06)", "[1.2426e+06,1.2431e+06)", "[1.2422e+06,1.2426e+06)", 
"[1.2417e+06,1.2422e+06)", "[1.2413e+06,1.2417e+06)", "[1.2408e+06,1.2413e+06)", 
"[1.2404e+06,1.2408e+06)", "[1.2399e+06,1.2404e+06)", "[1.2395e+06,1.2399e+06)", 
"[1.239e+06,1.2395e+06)", "[1.2386e+06,1.239e+06)", "[1.2381e+06,1.2386e+06)", 
"[1.2377e+06,1.2381e+06)", "[1.2372e+06,1.2377e+06)", "[1.2368e+06,1.2372e+06)"
), x = c("[2.6713e+06,2.6718e+06)", "[2.6718e+06,2.6722e+06)", 
"[2.6722e+06,2.6727e+06)", "[2.6727e+06,2.6732e+06)", "[2.6732e+06,2.6736e+06)", 
"[2.6736e+06,2.6741e+06)", "[2.6741e+06,2.6746e+06)", "[2.6746e+06,2.675e+06)", 
"[2.675e+06,2.6755e+06)", "[2.6755e+06,2.676e+06)", "[2.676e+06,2.6764e+06)", 
"[2.6764e+06,2.6769e+06)", "[2.6769e+06,2.6774e+06)", "[2.6774e+06,2.6778e+06)", 
"[2.6778e+06,2.6783e+06)", "[2.6783e+06,2.6788e+06)", "[2.6788e+06,2.6792e+06)", 
"[2.6792e+06,2.6797e+06)", "[2.6797e+06,2.6802e+06)", "[2.6802e+06,2.6806e+06)", 
"[2.6806e+06,2.6811e+06)", "[2.6811e+06,2.6816e+06)", "[2.6816e+06,2.682e+06)", 
"[2.682e+06,2.6825e+06)", "[2.6825e+06,2.683e+06)", "[2.683e+06,2.6834e+06)", 
"[2.6834e+06,2.6839e+06)", "[2.6839e+06,2.6844e+06)", "[2.6844e+06,2.6848e+06)", 
"[2.6848e+06,2.6853e+06)", "[2.6853e+06,2.6858e+06)", "[2.6858e+06,2.6862e+06)", 
"[2.6862e+06,2.6867e+06)", "[2.6867e+06,2.6872e+06)", "[2.6872e+06,2.6876e+06)", 
"[2.6876e+06,2.6881e+06)", "[2.6881e+06,2.6886e+06)", "[2.6886e+06,2.689e+06)", 
"[2.689e+06,2.6895e+06)", "[2.6895e+06,2.6899e+06)", "[2.6899e+06,2.6904e+06)", 
"[2.6904e+06,2.6909e+06)", "[2.6909e+06,2.6913e+06)", "[2.6913e+06,2.6918e+06)", 
"[2.6918e+06,2.6923e+06)", "[2.6923e+06,2.6927e+06)", "[2.6927e+06,2.6932e+06)", 
"[2.6932e+06,2.6937e+06)", "[2.6937e+06,2.6941e+06)", "[2.6941e+06,2.6946e+06]"
)), class = c("quadratcount", "table"), xbreaks = c(2671317, 
2671782.76, 2672248.52, 2672714.28, 2673180.04, 2673645.8, 2674111.56, 
2674577.32, 2675043.08, 2675508.84, 2675974.6, 2676440.36, 2676906.12, 
2677371.88, 2677837.64, 2678303.4, 2678769.16, 2679234.92, 2679700.68, 
2680166.44, 2680632.2, 2681097.96, 2681563.72, 2682029.48, 2682495.24, 
2682961, 2683426.76, 2683892.52, 2684358.28, 2684824.04, 2685289.8, 
2685755.56, 2686221.32, 2686687.08, 2687152.84, 2687618.6, 2688084.36, 
2688550.12, 2689015.88, 2689481.64, 2689947.4, 2690413.16, 2690878.92, 
2691344.68, 2691810.44, 2692276.2, 2692741.96, 2693207.72, 2693673.48, 
2694139.24, 2694605), ybreaks = c(1236783, 1237233.14, 1237683.28, 
1238133.42, 1238583.56, 1239033.7, 1239483.84, 1239933.98, 1240384.12, 
1240834.26, 1241284.4, 1241734.54, 1242184.68, 1242634.82, 1243084.96, 
1243535.1, 1243985.24, 1244435.38, 1244885.52, 1245335.66, 1245785.8, 
1246235.94, 1246686.08, 1247136.22, 1247586.36, 1248036.5, 1248486.64, 
1248936.78, 1249386.92, 1249837.06, 1250287.2, 1250737.34, 1251187.48, 
1251637.62, 1252087.76, 1252537.9, 1252988.04, 1253438.18, 1253888.32, 
1254338.46, 1254788.6, 1255238.74, 1255688.88, 1256139.02, 1256589.16, 
1257039.3, 1257489.44, 1257939.58, 1258389.72, 1258839.86, 1259290
), tess = structure(list(type = "rect", window = structure(list(
    type = "rectangle", xrange = c(2671317, 2694605), yrange = c(1236783, 
    1259290), units = structure(list(singular = "unit", plural = "units", 
        multiplier = 1), class = "unitname")), class = "owin"), 
    xgrid = c(2671317, 2671782.76, 2672248.52, 2672714.28, 2673180.04, 
    2673645.8, 2674111.56, 2674577.32, 2675043.08, 2675508.84, 
    2675974.6, 2676440.36, 2676906.12, 2677371.88, 2677837.64, 
    2678303.4, 2678769.16, 2679234.92, 2679700.68, 2680166.44, 
    2680632.2, 2681097.96, 2681563.72, 2682029.48, 2682495.24, 
    2682961, 2683426.76, 2683892.52, 2684358.28, 2684824.04, 
    2685289.8, 2685755.56, 2686221.32, 2686687.08, 2687152.84, 
    2687618.6, 2688084.36, 2688550.12, 2689015.88, 2689481.64, 
    2689947.4, 2690413.16, 2690878.92, 2691344.68, 2691810.44, 
    2692276.2, 2692741.96, 2693207.72, 2693673.48, 2694139.24, 
    2694605), ygrid = c(1236783, 1237233.14, 1237683.28, 1238133.42, 
    1238583.56, 1239033.7, 1239483.84, 1239933.98, 1240384.12, 
    1240834.26, 1241284.4, 1241734.54, 1242184.68, 1242634.82, 
    1243084.96, 1243535.1, 1243985.24, 1244435.38, 1244885.52, 
    1245335.66, 1245785.8, 1246235.94, 1246686.08, 1247136.22, 
    1247586.36, 1248036.5, 1248486.64, 1248936.78, 1249386.92, 
    1249837.06, 1250287.2, 1250737.34, 1251187.48, 1251637.62, 
    1252087.76, 1252537.9, 1252988.04, 1253438.18, 1253888.32, 
    1254338.46, 1254788.6, 1255238.74, 1255688.88, 1256139.02, 
    1256589.16, 1257039.3, 1257489.44, 1257939.58, 1258389.72, 
    1258839.86, 1259290), n = 2500), class = c("tess", "list"
)))
```

My goal is to either create a subset of all the rectangles that have a `Freq` above 100, or add a separate column with a binary classification if the row has a `Freq` above 100 or not.

My approach was to create a `data.frame` first and then the idea would be to change it back to a spatial data format. This is my unsuccessful approach:

```
Qdf <- as.data.frame(Q)
Qdf <- subset(Qdf, Qdf$Freq>100)
```

From here on I am unable to further display the data on a map.

Your help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `spatstat` package.  But, since your data are basically in a spatial raster grid, you could convert them to `raster` format and use`library(raster)` for spatial operations like subsetting, reclassifying, and displaying on maps:

```
xr = attributes(Q)$xbreaks[c(1, dim(Q)[1]+1L)]
yr = attributes(Q)$ybreaks[c(1, dim(Q)[2]+1L)]
r = raster(matrix(Q, nrow(Q)), xmn=xr[1], xmx=xr[2], ymn=yr[1], ymx=yr[2])
plot(r)
```

[image]

Now we can see where the count is greater than 100

```
plot(r>100)
```

[image]

Or, see the values, only where they are greater than 100.

```
r100 = reclassify(r, cbind(-Inf, 100, NA), right=FALSE)
plot(r100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this is precisely what I was looking for:)

Comment: This is not correct, in general. The `xbreaks` and `ybreaks` which you extracted from the internal structure of `Q` are not necessarily equally spaced - this is only the default behaviour. So it is not true that "your data are basically in a spatial raster grid". Indeed if `Q` had been created by a different call to `quadratcount`, the cells would be the tiles of a spatial tessellation rather than a raster. This is all documented in the help for `spatstat::quadratcount`. See the response by Ege Rubak for a correct  approach.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianBaddeley I did not claim anywhere that this would work for data that are not in a regular grid.  But these data are, so why not use rasters in that case?  For different analyses of course one might prefer a different method. But that does not make this "incorrect".

Comment: The question asks: "I have the following data that indicates how many points occur within each rectangle (spatial data generated with `quadratcount` from the `spatstat` package)" It is **not true** in general that such data are "basically in a spatial raster grid". The rectangles could be unequal in size and shape. So this answer is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Did you start with a planar point pattern (`ppp`) and then create the
quadratcount from there? In that case I recommend you use `pixellate` to get
the counts directly in a raster format (`im` class in `spatstat`):

```r
library(spatstat)
X <- bei
plot(X, main = "")
```

[image]

```r
nx <- 10
ny <- 5
Xqc <- quadratcount(bei, nx = nx, ny = ny)
plot(Xqc, main = "")
```

[image]

```r
Xim <- pixellate(X, dimyx = c(ny, nx))
plot(Xim , main = "")
plot(Xqc, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
Xim2 <- Xim[Xim>100, drop=FALSE] # If drop=TRUE vector of values is returned
plot(Xim2, main = "")
```

[image]